# AddOn Management in multiple CME instances

Tags: sites-9.5, add-on

We have a configuration for prod with to boxes:

- One for CME
- One for Publisher

Using AddOn we want to deploy a CustomResolver and an EventHandler that affects both boxes.

How we have to configure AddOn to "register" both servers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you already installed CME and Publisher servers then try the following script to add
[Enabling Add-ons Service integration with existing Content Manager servers](https://docs.sdl.com/816112/796604/sdl-tridion-sites-9-5/enabling-------------add-ons-service-integration-with-an-existing-content-manager-server)

**Example:**

```
.\EnableAddOnService.ps1 -AddOnServiceUrl http://
localhost:83 -AccessManagementUrl http://localhost:85/access-management/connect/token -ClientId fc96aed3-b20e-4dd3-a345-
81e4393224c3 -ClientSecret aZL7QrEM5XRfbLYv6Z5s781gzamqGM0sp2dUfot4y4ljadRN5kxX5A==
```

I hope it helps